# In App Purchase Test

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, subscription

I want to implement In App Billing Subscriptions in my application to remove the ads from my application for the user.

I have made a test apk and added products to purchase via In App Billing in it. The process is working fine. but I want to do more testing in it, so I put my email id in the License panel; BUT THE PROBLEM IS IT IS STILL DEDUCTING MONEY WHEN MAKE A PURCHASE WITH THAT EMAIL ID> This is a test order... is not written on the purchase dialog.

Answer (score 0):

First upload your Apk in beta testing and put your id into setting and then check . it will complete as it work even it mail you but it will not deduct your amount.
u must have your in app unpublished to test on beta or alpa testing to uncharge.

Comment: this is not working, it is saying - This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play..

Comment: done that also. then the above error doesnot comes, but I my credit card is charged. I want to enable the test account for the same